# Java Programming, Window Size Predicament

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, size

I'm creating a program that coverts a matrix to graphics. It takes the matrix goes through it and then will display 10*10 boxes. Everything works correct but here's my problem.

Lets say i want to make a matrix[3][3] so that the image would be 30 by 30 when i make my JFrame 30*30 it is way to small. This is probably a beginner mistake but i suspect that im not including the border?

So its making squares that are 10 by 10 and the JFrame size is 30,30 but the Space inside the JFrame is way smaller then it should be.

```
public void paint(Graphics w){
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row ++ )
     for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++ )
     {
        if(a[row][col]==1){
            w.fillRect(col*10, row*10, 10,10);
        }
        x+=10;
     }
}
```

Could you, please, explain how big the border of the window is so that i can make my JFrame the correct size? Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: The wording is alright, but the lack of code hurts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows (and frames) have decorations around them, which sit inside the frames bound relies, so if you make the frame 30x30, the frames viewable size will be be smaller.

What you want to do is override the `getPreferredSize` method of you primary container which returns (in this example), 30x30 and the call `pack` on the frame.

This will resize the window in such away so that the viewable area will be at least 30x30

Comment: I'm not quite understanding do you mind trying to explain it "easier" thanks! Im only im Computer Science AP so im not an "expert" yep :) thanks!

Comment: Basically, create yourself a new class that extends from do,egg like JPanel, override its getPreferredSize method and return the size of the component you need. Use this to display your matrix and add it to your frame. When your ready, call "pack()" just before you call setVisible